# Changing number format in excel

Tags: excel

I stuck with some formating problem.

I have numbers like this

```
49.785.011
14.740.397
14.167.482
13.111.053
12.735.113
12.524.514
10.513.046
```

I want to format them to be like this

```
€49,785,011
€14,740,397
€14,167,482
€13,111,053
€12,735,113
€12,524,514
€10,513,046
```

Which formula or which formatting I should use to have this result? I have 2 tables of ± 10000 rows each, so changing it manually doesn't look so cool.

EDIT1:

This is how it looks in excel table itself.[image]

Comment: Are those numbers or text values looking like numbers and what is your desired result? Numbers or again, a text looking like numbers but formatted?

Comment: @JvdV Numbers will be better, but honestly I just need them to format with commas and euro sign in front of number (text).

Comment: But do you have numbers to start of with? Or are those string values?

Comment: @JvdV please take a look at the edited quesiton, I add a screenshot of excel table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula `=TEXT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(Cell_To_Convert,".","")),"€#,##")` to convert the cell value to number and format it as euro currency with commas.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need to know if Excel understand these numbers as **text**, or as **numbers**:

1. Go to one of the cells that contains the number and select it.
2. Check in the formula bar, if it has the number has already any formatting in place

   A) If you read "49.785.011" it is already formatted. For Excel it is text, not a number.

   B) If you read "49785011", but the cell shows the separators, For Excel it is a number.

In case you are in A situation (text), you need to remove the dots (.). For this you can do a Search & Replace, and replace all dots by nothing. This will convert your cells content into numbers. Now we can apply desired formatting.

What you are asking for, is called Currency formatting. Basically select the columns needed and use Right Click > Format Cells...

[image]

Then you can select formatting desired:

[image]